# function triggering for previously opened VC

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table view.  When I click a cell, it takes me to a page where I can edit the data and it passes all the information from the cell.  Then I can click "save"/"delete" and it posts the changes to/deletes the item from firebase.  Then it takes me back to the table view and pulls the newly updated firebase data.

**Problem**

However, if I delete an item (on the page where I can edit/delete details), then get transitioned back to the table view, then click on a different cell and edit and save, it posts the edited item **AND** the previously deleted item.  It doesn't even make sense to me how this is possible.

**Investigation**

I tried deleting an item, killing the app, reopening, *and then* saving a different cell.  In this case, the error does not occur.   This leads me to believe that there may be some sort of memory/memory leak issue, but I'm not sure how I can truly resolve this issue.

**My Attempt**

**ViewController with TableView**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ItemListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    //reference to firebase database
    var ref : DatabaseReference?
    var handle : DatabaseHandle?
    var allItemData : [String:Any] = [:]
    // Get current userID
    let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) ?? ""
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var addItemOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfItemsTextBox: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set up tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 69
        // Set up UIPickerView (dropdown for numberOfItemsTextBox)
        setUpPickers()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // fetch user's item data from firebase
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        handle = ref?.child("users").child(userID).child("items").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // replace the old array
            self.allItemData = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            // reload the UITableView
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.setEnableForAddOutlet()
        })
        // Get numberOfItems
        ref.child("user/" + userID + "/items/numberOfItems").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                self.numberOfItemsTextBox.text = ""
            } else {
                // successfully fetched value
                value = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!
                self.numberOfItemsTextBox.text = numberOfItems
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func save() {
        print("post the value for numberOfItems to firebase")
        let itemsToPost : [String: Any] = [
            "numberOfItems" : numberOfItemsTextBox.text ?? "",
        ]
        for item in items {
            self.ref.child("users/" + userID + "/items").child(item.key).setValue(item.value)
        }
    }

    // Action when the return key pressed
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("running textFieldShouldReturn")
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func setEnableForAddOutlet() {
        if (allItemData.count > 1) {
            addItemOutlet.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            addItemOutlet.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    ////////////////
    // BUTTONS
    @IBAction func addItemButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Save
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"ItemAdd", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Save
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"mySegueToADifferentPlace", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Save
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"mySegueToSomeWhereElse", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Save
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"mySegueToSomeWhereElse", sender: nil)
    }

    // End of [BUTTONS]
    ////////////////

    ////////////////
    // TABLE VIEW

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItemData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! itemListCell
        let key = Array(allItemData.keys)[indexPath.row]
        let item = (allItemData[key] as? [String:Any]) ?? [:]
        let name = (item["name"] as? String) ?? ""
        let year = (item["year"] as? String) ?? ""
        cell.titleLabel?.text = name
        cell.itemID = key
        cell.name = name
        cell.year = year
        cell.other = (item["other"] as? String) ?? ""
        cell.state = (item["state"] as? String) ?? ""

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"ItemEdit", sender: nil)
    }

    // End of [TABLE VIEW]
    ////////////////


    //////////
    // Picker Controllers


    //Arrays for picker views
    let numOfItemsArray = ["0", "1", "2", "2+"]
    let errorArray = ["unable to load"]

    let itemPickerView = UIPickerView()

    func setUpPickers() {
        print("running setUpPickers")
        // new picker
        itemPickerView.delegate = self
        numberOfItemsTextBox.inputView = itemPickerView
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print("setting titleForRow...")
        if pickerView == itemPickerView {
            return numOfItemsArray[row]
        } else {
            return errorArray[0]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("setting numberOfRowsInComponent...")
        if pickerView == itemPickerView {
            return numOfItemsArray.count
        } else {
            return errorArray.count
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        print("setting numberOfComponents...")
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("setting didSelectRow...")

        if pickerView == itemPickerView {
            //change the text in the textField equal to the selection
            let value = numOfItemsArray[row]
            numberOfItemsTextBox.text = value
            if value == numOfItemsArray[0] {
                numberOfItemsTextBox.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            } else {
                numberOfItemsTextBox.textColor = UIColor.black
            }
        }
        numberOfItemsTextBox.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //
    //////////


    ///////////////////
    //MARK: - Navigation
    //In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ItemEdit" {
            // get the indexPath of the selected cell
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                // get the selected cell
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! itemListCell
                // get an instance of the next ViewController
                let itemController : EditVC = segue.destination as! EditVC
                // take all the data from the selected cell and pass it to the next ViewController
                print("itemController variables")
                itemController.itemID = cell.itemID
                itemController.name = cell.name
                itemController.year = cell.year
                itemController.other = cell.other
                itemController.state = cell.state
            } else {
                // tell the user if the indexPath of the selected cell cannot be retrieved
                print("Unable to select item")
            }
        }
    }
    //////////////////
}
```

**ViewController to edit/delete**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class EditVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var otherTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateTextField: UITextField!

    // Variables for items's Details
    var itemID = ""
    var name = ""
    var year = ""
    var other = ""
    var state = ""

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        //for shifting textFields when keyboard covers
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        setUpPickers()

        // Set initial values for TextFields
        nameTextField.text = name
        yearTextField.text = year
        otherTextField.text = other
        stateTextField.text = state
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /////////////////////////
    // Buttons
    @IBAction func returnButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTableView", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if itemID != "" {
            print("removing item")
            self.ref.child("users").child(userID).child("items").child(itemID).removeValue();
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTableView", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        save()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTableView", sender: self)
    }
    // End of [Buttons]
    /////////////////////////

    func save() {
        // Create an items object to post
        // Get the values from all textfields and set in the object
        let itemsToPost : [String: Any] = [
            "name": nameTextField.text ?? "",
            "year": yearTextField.text ?? "",
            "state": stateTextField.text ?? "",
            "other": otherTextField.text ?? ""
        ]
        // if the user is saving a new item (itemID == ""), then create a new ID and set itemID
        if (itemID == "") {
            itemID = ref.child("users/" + userID + "/items").childByAutoId().key
        }
        // post the items object to firebase
        for item in items {
            self.ref.child("users/" + userID + "/items/" + itemID).child(item.key).setValue(item.value)
        }
    }

    //////////
    // Picker Controllers

    //Arrays for picker views
    let stateArray = ["State", "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
    var yearArray : [String] = []
    let errorArray = ["unable to load"]

    let yearPickerView = UIPickerView()
    let statePickerView = UIPickerView()

    func setUpPickers() {
        print("running setUpPickers")
        // new picker
        yearPickerView.delegate = self
        yearTextField.inputView = yearPickerView
        statePickerView.delegate = self
        stateTextField.inputView = statePickerView

        var i = 1900
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let maxYear = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        while i < (maxYear + 1) {
            yearArray.insert(String(describing: i), at: 0)
            i += 1
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print("setting titleForRow...")
        if pickerView == statePickerView {
            return stateArray[row]
        } else if pickerView == yearPickerView {
            return yearArray[row]
        } else {
            return errorArray[0]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("setting numberOfRowsInComponent...")
        if pickerView == statePickerView {
            return stateArray.count
        } else if pickerView == yearPickerView {
            return yearArray.count
        } else {
            return errorArray.count
        }
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        print("setting numberOfComponents...")
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("setting didSelectRow...")

        if pickerView == statePickerView {
            print("setting text of stateTextField")
            stateTextField.text = stateArray[row]

            if stateTextField.text == stateArray[0] {
                stateTextField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            } else {
                stateTextField.textColor = UIColor.black
            }
        } else if pickerView == yearPickerView {
            print("setting text of yearTextField")
            yearTextField.text = yearArray[row]

            if yearTextField.text == stateArray[0] {
                yearTextField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            } else {
                yearTextField.textColor = UIColor.black
            }
        }
    }

    //
    //////////


    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // shifting text fields (add listeners in viewDidLoad)
    func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
        print("running keyboardWillShow...")
        //give room at the bottom of the scroll view, so it doesn't cover up anything the user needs to tap
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = (keyboardFrame.size.height + 60)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
        print("running keyboardWillHide...")
        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset

        print("saving...")
        save()
        print("finished keyboardWillHide...")
    }
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////
}
```

**Does anyone know why this bizarre functionality is occurring and how to resolve it?**

Thank you in advance for any ideas

Comment: If you comment the line performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTableView", sender: self) from deleteButtonPressed from second viewcontroller and then run the code, see what is the result?

Comment: Try writing a perpareForSegue for "backToTableView" then use this space to set all of you passed in variables back to "".  Then see if it still posts the deleted information when you reload.

Comment: @DoesData, thank you for the suggestion; it was a good thought.  I did try setting the variables back to "" with a `prepareForSegue`, but this actually made even more duplicates

Comment: @3stud1ant3 thanks for the suggestion.  If I comment out that segue, I can't get back to the tableview to test if this issue

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code that's going to cause 'weird' issues. First is that when one item is deleted, it reloads ALL items, which is really a waste of bandwidth. My suggestion is that when one item is deleted, remove that one item from the dataSource instead of reloading everything. Secondly since you are loading all of the items into an array (and will therefore have array.count) why keep a separate node to store the count? Also, isn't the viewDidAppear going to be called every time you segue back to the master and reloading again after it was just reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

---

**Solution:**

remove `save()` from the `keyboardWillHide` function

---

**Reasoning**

In case it helps others, the issue was that the `keyboardWillHide` method invokes `save()`.  In cases where saving means posting to **fixed keys**, this is no issue and in fact possibly even very convenient since every time you finish editing a field, the keyboard hides and it saves your data to firebase. *But*, since we're posting to unique keys (the `itemID`) rather than the same key everytime, this generates duplicate calls for keys to be created and saved to firebase.  Then, back on the controller with Table View, all those duplicate values that were just saved to firebase are then loaded.